# 415 Unsupported Media Type in post request

Tags: vue.js, post, vuejs2, request, frontend

Does anyone know what could cause ERROR 415  (Unsupported Media Type)? Thank you

```
  createArticleOld : async ({ commit, dispatch }, data) => {
    let added = await dispatch('authorizedPostOld', 
        { action: 'article',
          data, 
          headers:  {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
            'Accept': 'application/json-patch+json',
          },
        }
    )
    console.log(added)
    commit('ADD_ARTICLE', added)
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, an HTTP response status of 415 is telling you that the format of the data you're sending isn't accepted by the server, as described briefly [here](https://httpstatuses.com/415):

> The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.
>
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

So, to solve the problem, you need to find out the format that the server expects to receive data in, and send that. The easiest way will be to check the documentation for (or ask the developer of) the server.

If you check the raw response returned to your browser (or perform the same request via something like cURL or Postman), you might find some clues in there as to the formats that the endpoint accepts, or the specific problem causing the error response.

Of course, this relies on the developer of the server implementing the HTTP statuses correctly, and it's quite possible that they've made an error. As a complete guess, given that you're setting the `Accept` header, it *could* be that the server is trying to tell you that it can't give you a response in the format "application/json-patch+json", although that *should* give you a [406](https://httpstatuses.com/406).